# Column Currency Format on DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, jtable, format

I'm trying to use a `DefaultTableModel` and place in a column format, but not make changes.
How I can put Currency format in a column in a `DefaultTableModel`?

```
String iSql = "SELECT cod_pro, name_pro, price_pro,stock_pro  from product";
String[] r = {"ID","Product","Price","Stock"};
String [] Data = new String[4];
model = new DefaultTableModel(null,r);
try{
    Statement jSt = jcn.Con().createStatement();
    ResultSet jRst = jSt.executeQuery(iSql);
    while(jRst.next()){
        Data[0] = jRst.getString("cod_pro");
        Data[1]= jRst.getString("name_pro");
        Data[2]= jRst.getString("price_pro");
        Data[3]= jRst.getString("stock_pro");
        modelo.addRow(Data);
    }
    tblProduct.setModel(model);
    TableColumnModel m = tblProduct.getColumnModel();
    m.getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer()); 
}
catch(SQLException ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR " + ex);
}
```

Comment: You're setting the model on `tblProducto`, and you're setting the renderer on `tblProduct`.

Comment: same, no works :) thansk for you reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don`t know a method to do what you want but you could do a trick like this

```
Data[2]= "Currency"+jRst.getString("price_pro");
```

but when your retrieving data you have to split it or substring it

Comment: how split it substring , trim?
txtPrice.setText(tblProduct.getValueAt(rower, 3).toString().substring(3))